# Wordpress post page get 404 but Homepage works

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already red a lot about this problem, but non of the solutions helped me out. I installed a fresh Wordpress on my Apache. After changing the permalink structure from default (www.domain.com/?p=id) to another one, wordpress delivers me an 404 error for each page except the homepage.

I already checked the following:

- mod_rewrite is installed and enabled (checked through phpinfo)
- .htaccess is read- and writable

Here is my default .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Using the plugin "Debug this", I could also find out, that the rewrite rule always deliveres additional index.php? at the beginning. E.g. `sitemap_index\.xml$` is rewrited as `index.php?sitemap=1`

What can I do so solve the problem? Default links like www.domain.com/?p=1 but that kills all my SEO.

Edit: After the installation, there was also `/index.php/%postname%` written in the custom permalink. But this setting is also returning a 404.

Comment: Is your installation under a subdirectory of the webroot?

Comment: It's under /var/www/ and there I created an new folder for that.

Comment: when it happens to me I go to permalink in admin and I reset the permalink to the default structure www.domain.com/?p=123 then I save and I try to set it again on the desired structure. After saving usually everything comes back to normality.

Comment: I also tested this out. On different Wordpress instances, this also helped me out. But in this case, it is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

open this file

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

chnage all AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All and restart your apache
after that update your permalink structure to post and update it.

path can be different from "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

Comment: Finally that was the problem! I just changed it from None to All! Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: For Apache 2.4 running under Windows 10 on localhost, I had to edit httpd.conf. In section <Directory /> I had to change the default for AllowOverride from None to All.

Answer (score 2):

In my Ubuntu server VirtualBox VM this problem was caused by `apache2` not having the `rewrite` mod enabled.  What I did:

1. `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable mod-rewrite.
2. In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` inside the `<Directory>` entry for my folder I changed

- This:  `AllowOverride None`
- To this:
  `AllowOverride FileInfo`

3. `sudo service apache2 restart`

And now I can permalink.  Shoutout to the thousands of people saying just click save settings on your permalink page to fix the 404

Comment: You legend! Had to pick up a WordPress build that was abandoned and this was confusing the heck out of me. This fixed the issue.

Comment: `AllowOverride FileInfo` worked for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

go to your permalink settings and change the permalink structure to "post name" and update your permalink structure. hope it will help.

Comment: I already tried out to take another structure. This failed. What to you mean be updating the permalink structure? Should I just select another structure and that's it or is there also another option to completely update it?

Comment: remove your htaccess code. and then set your permalink strure to post name and update it

Comment: your site is on local server or on live server

Comment: I removed the code in the htaccess and reset the structure. Unfortunately same problem. It's on a live server.

Comment: can you give live url of your website? is it linux hosting or windows hosting

Comment: I think you are using centos

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04. The URL is https://www.umzuege-ruhrgebiet.de Just try out https://www.umzuege-ruhrgebiet.de/privatumzug/umzugsunternehmen-bochum/ and you will get the error. The page is still in progress but content is already put in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159059/discussion-between-rajkumar-gour-and-ds87).

Comment: i've put the solution on chat please follow this

Comment: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
open this file
chnage all AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
and restart your apache
after that update yout permalink structure to post and update it
path can be different from " 
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"